# What is the difference between 50/51N relay and 50/51G relay

Tags: relay, electric-machine, electrically-conductive

On electrical engineering field of power distribution. When it comes to ground fault detection on solidly grounded or low resistance grounded transformers. When do we use 50/51N relay and 50/51G, do they accomplish the same function ?

Comment: Where did you see these designations?  If they are part numbers, please give a link to their datasheet.  The numbers, by themselves, don't mean anything to me.

Comment: These are ANSI standard device, it's used for power system protection

Comment: Did you do any research? There's a lot of info about this if you just Google...

Comment: First hit on google has all the answers: http://electrical-engineering-portal.com/applications-and-characteristics-of-overcurrent-relays-ansi-50-51 Didn't take me very long to find out - why couldn't you?

Comment: Question should be closed - no research.

Answer (score 4):

50 and 51 are types of overcurrent relays (relays driven by a current transformer). Type 50 is an "instantaneous off" relay, whereas type 51 has an inbuilt time delay.

The N, G, etc depicts not what the relay is, but *how it is wired up*.

- N = Neutral CT connection
- G = "Zero Sequence" CT connection

That is, the N is wired to a current transformer around the neutral (earth connected) point of a star (Y) 3-phase system. The G is connected to three series connected current transformers, one on each phase of a 3-phase system:

[image]

In both systems the relays are the same - it is merely the arrangement of current transformers and where they get their feed from that changes.

Comment: Do they measure the same value even if the wiring is different ?

Comment: They are basically the industrial equivalent of the household RCD. Any current above a threshold flowing through the neutral/ground of type N or any imbalance above a threshold in the phases of type G will induce a current in the current transformers which will drive the relay to open and cut off the power.

Comment: @Majenko. The image you are showing belongs to a zero sequence CT however in the description you mentioned 3 individual CTs. This is wrong. In a zero sequence CT the 3 phase conductors are passed through the window of 1 big sized CT